# Is there a way to get messages from specific user

Tags: facebook, message, inbox

Is it possible to get messages from specific user?

If I would like to get all messages where recipients are myself and x

I didn't find a way to create that kind of query, so is it possible?

Comment: So is it possible to get that thread somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fbid = your_fbuid_here;          
        FB.api({
                    method: 'fql.query',
                    query: 'SELECT thread_id, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND author_id = ' + fbid + ' ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 1'
                }, function ( threadresponse ) {
                    FB.api({
                        method: 'fql.query',
                        query: 'SELECT thread_id, body, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id = ' + threadresponse[0].thread_id + ' ORDER BY created_time ASC'
                    }, function ( inboxresponse ) {
                            //do stuff here with results
                    });
                });
```

or you can do this

```
 var fbid =the _freind_fb_uid_here;          
            FB.api({
                        method: 'fql.query',
                        query: 'SELECT thread_id, body, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND author_id = ' + fbid + ' ORDER BY created_time DESC'
                    }, function ( threadresponse ) {
                                //do stuff here with results
                    });
```

[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-fql](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql)[facebook-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-api)[facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api)[facebook-fql-query](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql-query)

Comment: Hmm, this returns my first thread, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: your_fbuid is the one of the person you want to match the messages. The first query is to get the thread_id from the thread fql, the second fql is to get all the messages.

Comment: well I can also be the author in the messaging thread, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Now FQL don't have field `author_id`, only `originator` and `snippet_author`. But this fields contain wrong data. For example, userA send me (userB) message: userA create thread. Anyway I see, that originator have me (userB).

Best way use `recipients`:

```
SELECT recipients,snippet,object_id,updated_time,unread,unseen,thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id=0 AND recipients IN (userA_fid, userB_fid)
```

But it's also don't work and return empty data...